# create a data entry form in Rshiny that clears answers

Tags: r, shiny

Based on these question and answers [Add a new row with the existing data frame in shiny R by using action button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47083893/add-a-new-row-with-the-existing-data-frame-in-shiny-r-by-using-action-button) and [adding data input into a empty data frame in R using shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60733099/adding-data-input-into-a-empty-data-frame-in-r-using-shiny) I am trying to build a shiny app that can be used a data entry form. so after the 4 questions are entered, the user clicks submit, all the fields are reset and emptied and the user can add a new patient. after every submit the patient gets appended to the dataframe. I am getting the data entry to work, but not the appending and clearing of the cells. (Ideally there also would be an option to download the whole dataframe to excel, but I think that will be a next step).

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

# Define UI -----------
# ---------------------

ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("sandstone"),
                
                # header
                headerPanel("My Shiny Data entry app"),
                
                sidebarLayout(
                    # sidebar for form
                    sidebarPanel(
                        h3("Information",""),
                        textInput("name", "Patient Name",""),
                        textInput("age", "Patient Age",""),
                        textInput("id", "Patient ID",""),
                        radioButtons("gender", "Patient gender",
                                     c("None selected" = "",
                                         "male",
                                       "female" ,
                                       "other" ,
                                       "do no want to say")),
                        actionButton("update", "Next patient")
                    ),
                    
                    # output for viewing
                    mainPanel(
                        
                        DT::dataTableOutput("tableDT"),
                        
                        
                    )   
                )
)

# Define server logic ------
# --------------------------

server <- function(input, output) {
    
    # process the textinput
    table_1 <- reactive({  
        
        
        # creating table
        
        aniRoi2 <- data.frame(Animal_ID = input$name, 
                              Scan_ID = input$age, 
                              Tech_ID = input$id, 
                              Age_weeks = input$gender, 
                              stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
        
        return(aniRoi2)
    })
    
    # process the text file and download
    
    
    
    # merge two function as data.frame
    mytable2 <-eventReactive(input$update,{
        
        table_1()
         #cbind.data.frame(table_1(), mytable2())
        
    })
    
    
    # output as data table      
    output$tableDT <- DT::renderDataTable(
        mytable2()
    )
    
    
}

# Run the app ----------
# ----------------------
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work :

```
## Initilializing empty data.frame
aniRoi2 <- reactiveVal(data.frame(Animal_ID = character(), 
                              Scan_ID = character(), 
                              Tech_ID = character(), 
                              Age_weeks = character(), 
                              stringsAsFactors = FALSE))

observeEvent(input$update,{
    to_add <- data.frame(
          Animal_ID = input$name, 
          Scan_ID = input$age, 
          Tech_ID = input$id, 
          Age_weeks = input$gender
          )
    newAniRoi2 <- rbind(aniRoi2(),to_add) # adding new data
    aniRoi2(newAniRoi2) # updating data

    # Cleaning Inputs
    updateTextInput(session,"name", "Patient Name","")),
    updateTextInput(session,"age", "Patient Age","")),
    updateTextInput(session,"id", "Patient ID","")),
    updateRadioButtons(session,"gender", "Patient gender",
                       c("None selected" = "",
                         "male",
                         "female" ,
                         "other" ,
                         "do no want to say")))
    
  })

output$tableDT <- DT::renderDataTable(
        aniRoi2()
    )
```

Do not forget to add the session argument inside your build :

```
server <- function(input, output, session) { #don't forget the session argument here
```

Basically, this resets the inputs into their original form. Maybe you can include this chunk of code (without the observeEvent) inside your eventReactive. If you do so, put it after the loading of the data to prevent from an eventual fail of the precedent functions.

Comment: Thank you! this does indeed clear the inputs, but does not yet append a new row to the data frame after every submission (my main problem), but just overrides them.

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't see that you couldn't do the appendix either. Editing...